# How can I save different plot to different name at one go?

Tags: matlab, plot, save, figure, subplot

Actually I have so many data. First, I read my txt data.

```
M=dlmread('a02_s01_e02_skeleton.txt', ' ');

M1=M(1:40:end,1)
M2=M(1:40:end,2) 
subplot(2,1,1) 
plot(M1)
grid on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(M2)
grid on
```

Then, This figure is what I want to save A1.jpg

```
M1=M(3:40:end,1)
M2=M(3:40:end,2)  % here is the difference
subplot(2,1,1) 
plot(M1)
grid on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(M2)
grid on
```

And for this, I want to save A2.jpg

The last one will be A20.jpg

I use saveas function but they just say,

> Cannot create output file 'A1.jpg.jpg'

And can I choose location to save?

Comment: what is the syntax of `saveas` that you are using? please post the exact command you are trying.

Comment: I just try to use **saveas** function.
It'll be ok to use other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `getframe` and `imwrite`:

```
for ii=1:20
    start = 1 + (ii-1)*2;
    M1 = M( start:40:end, 1 );
    M2 = M( start:40:end, 2 ); 
    subplot(1,2,1); plot( M1 ); grid on;
    subplot(1,2,2); plot( M2 ); grid on;
    % here is where the image is generated using getframe
    frm = getframe( gcf );
    imwrite( frm.cdata, sprintf( './A%d.jpg', ii ) );
end
```

You can modify the `imwrite` command to change the target directory:

```
imwrite( frm.cdata, fullfile( targetFolderName, sprintf( 'A%d.jpg', ii ) ) );
```

Comment: Can I commend to save directory where like C:\kanje ?

Comment: @KanjaePark just set `targetFolderName = 'c:\kanje';` and use the second `imwrite`: `imwrite( frm.cdata, fullfile( targetFolderName, sprintf( 'A%d.jpg', ii ) ) );`

Comment: there go well. Thx a lot

Comment: Can you help my another question??

Comment: I posted it several minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hgexport`

```
myPath = 'Your path here';

for ii=1:20
  plotName = strcat(myPath,strcat('A',num2str(ii))); % Path + Name of the file
  newPlot = figure();
  %% Your different plots
  hgexport(newPlot,plot_name,hgexport('factorystyle'),'Format', 'jpeg');
end;
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95198-why-do-figures-exported-using-the-saveas-function-and-the-file-save-as-menu-item-have-different-res